# Help with differentiability of $\frac{x^6}{x^4 + y^4}$ at $(x,y)=(1,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Imagine you have the following function:
$$
f(x, y): \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R \\ \; \\
f(x) = \begin{cases}
      \frac{x^6}{x^4 + y^4} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \; \; \\
       \\
       0  & (x, y) \neq (0, 0)
       \\
     \end{cases}
$$
And I'm trying to prove that it is differentiable in $(x,y) = (1, 2)$
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{(1 + t)^6}{(1 + t)^4 + (2 + t)^4} - f(\mathbf x_0)  -  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x}(1, 2) \cdot(t,t) }{t}
$$
Computing we get the following:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(1 + t)^6 - f(\mathbf x_0) [(1 + t)^4 + (2 + t)^4]  -  t\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1, 2) -  t\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1, 2) }{t[(1 + t)^4 + (2 + t)^4]}
$$
We know that the partial derivatives exists, and the function value, also exists at $(1, 2)$.
But the thing is that this limit is undefined, but indeed the function is differentiable at that point, so, what I'm doing wrong? How would I compute this limit?

Comment: $f$ has continuous partial derivatives at all points except $(0,0)$

Comment: What you are trying to calculate is not the differential $Df_{(1,2)}:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R.$ You are calculating the limit as $t\to0$ of $\frac{f(1+t,2+t)-f(1,2)-Df_{(1,2)}(t,t)}t.$ And this limit is not undefined. It is $0,$ by definition of the differential. Or simply, because this quotient is $\frac{g(t)-g(0)}t-g'(0),$ where $g(t)=f(1+t,2+t).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{x^6}{x^4 + y^4}\right)=\frac{2x^9+6x^5y^4}{(x^4 + y^4)^2} $$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{x^6}{x^4 + y^4}\right)=-\frac{4y^3x^6}{(x^4 + y^4)^2} $$
Now compute the gradient at the point $(1,2)$:
$$\nabla f(1,2)=\left(\frac{98}{289},-\frac{128}{289} \right)$$
Finally compute the following limit to see if $f$ is differentiable:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(f(x,y)-f(1,2)-\langle\nabla{f}(1,2),(x-1,y-2)\rangle \right) $$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(\frac{x^6}{x^4 + y^4}-\frac{1}{17}-\frac{98}{289}(x-1) +\frac{128}{289} (y-2)\right)=0 $$
Hence the function is differentiable at $(x,y)=(1,2)$.